# Uploading large .bak file to Azure Blob through Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, blob, azure-blob-storage

So I am trying to create a powershell script which will upload a large (> 4GB) .Bak file to Azure Blob Storage but currently it is getting hung. This script **works** with small files which I have been using to test.

Originally the issue I was having was the requirement to have a Content-Length specified (I imagine due its size) so I now calculate the file size of the .bak file (as it varies slightly each week) and pass this through as a request header

I am a total powershell newbie, as well as being very new to Azure blob. (NOTE: I am trying to do this purely in powershell, without relying on other tools such as AzCopy)

Below is my script

[Powershell Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pysp1.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: PLEASE do **not** show code as a link to an image. Instead, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68496609/edit) and paste the code you have in there as formatted text. That aside, your `$bakFullPath` does not point to any file, only to the folder where the file may be in..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few things to check. Since file is big, are you sure it isn't uploading? Have you checked network activity in performance tab of task explorer? AzCopy seems like a good option too that you can use from within Powershell, but if it's not an option in your case, then why not to use native AZ module for Powershell?

I suggest you using `Set-AzStorageBlobContent` cmdlet to see if it helps. You can find examples at [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell#upload-blobs-to-the-container)